# Facing error while accessing submitted values please guide someone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im new to rails, and I am not able to understand how I can get data from a submitted form.

This is my form `registerduser.html.erb`

```
<%= form_tag("/submitform", :method => "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q1, "id:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q1) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```

How do I get the submitted values in this customers controller action?

```
def submitform
  @customers_values = params[:q1]
end
```

routes.rb

```
get "customers/submitform"
```

error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/submitform"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set wrong form url. It should be:

```
<%= form_tag('/customers/submitform', method: :get) do %>
...
```

or:

```
<%= form_tag(controller: :customers, action: :submitform, method: :get) do %>
...
```